# Cannot load Spring application context file using Android Studio, file does not exist

Tags: spring, android-studio, classpath, android-gradle-plugin, applicationcontext

I'm using AndroidStudio 1.1.0 and I am trying to load a Spring application context file using the following :

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = 
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

I get the following error :
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

I have placed the file in the src/main/res folder
I have also placed the file in the top level of src

I am not convinced it is making it into the generated .apk file?  How can I add this file to the .apk file ?

I suspect this is a gradle issue?  First time I have used Android Studio and gradle ... ?!

Answer (score 0):

OK - I had to add a JAR file and a gradle dependency to get it into the built APK file

```
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['applicationContext.jar'])
```